# Angular-strap modal shows empty

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-strap

I am trying to implement angular-strap modal, I have an external template of modal but it shows as blank. Whats wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.13" data-semver="1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularstrap@*" data-semver="2.1.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.2/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularstrap@*" data-semver="2.1.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.1.2/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-default" content-template="customer.tpl.html" bs-modal="modal">New Customer</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

[**Here's link to Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hbt4o57LND0e8kHp7WD6?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you need to fix:

The first is to replace `content-template` with `data-template`, and the second is that if you have `ng-bind="title"`, you need to have a title variable on the scope, because `ng-bind` replaces the content of the HTML element it's on with what it's binded to:

```
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-template="customer.tpl.html" bs-modal="modal">New Customer</button>
  </body>
```

To see the text in the modal, either remove `ng-bind="content"` from the body, or assign `content` variable some value.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNFy2XcOBefUavG1QCqD?p=preview).

Source: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##modals-examples

Comment: plunker works, but in my app it says 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefinedangular.js:2845 s.cssangular.js:2947 R.(anonymous function)typeahead.js:259 u.showtypeahead.js:259 u.toggleangular.js:3014 c

any idea why ?